# How to encode url parameter in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am working with Joomla component
Problem is:

I have an URL like this

```
http://localhost/Joomla_16/index.php/component/mycomponent_name/?view=mycomponent_view&cre=15
```

I want to encode the value of &cre=15

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does `&cre=15` need to encode?

Comment: for security purpose only. only value 15 needed to encode .is there anyway to do that xdazz?

Comment: @Nathanphan: why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

It is easy. Using [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php). silly me!